Sci-fi short story about a WW2 German secret project to create a portal to another world
Hey hey you wonderful people. Need help finding a short story.
It was part of a short story compendium whose book title I've unfortunately forgotten... probably written in the 80s or 70's. Granted this was 10 years ago, so bear with me as some of the details may or may not be inaccurate.
So the way the story is told is via top secret memos.
Set at the height of the Cold War during the 1950s, a CIA operative obtains top secret files via a defecting Russian KGB agent who failed to show up for his meet and is assumed to be captured and killed. The subject of the files is a Soviet investigation into the German Wunderwaffe program.
As you follow the story, the narrative switches to a Soviet NKVD agent post 1945, who's tasked with combing the ruins of Berlin for anything technology related. They come upon a bunch of files too fantastical to believe, but upon further investigation through the years, can conclude that most of the events the file describes did indeed happen.
The narrative then switches to a German POV, an unnamed Nazi security official investigating the events that happened based on interrogations and research.
In the 1930s, with Hitler's rise to power, there is an increase of funding to scientific projects. One project is viewed with such promise when a scientist develops a machine that can basically grab any resource they want, via a dimension or portal, essentially giving the Germans free unlimited resources. However he still needs time to calibrate it as the machine can only do so for a few minutes.
After reading the reports, Hitler increases spending of the project, and begins gearing up for war in Europe. A few years later when another demonstration shows that the machine can operate for hours instead of minutes; Hitler begins the invasion of Poland, kickstarting WWII and confident that this new machine will be their ace in the hole.
Fast forward to a few more years and based on the interrogations from the assistants who helped, the scientist who developed the project is starting to get a conscience as he initially developed the machine so that Germany could have resources it needs without starting wars, the very opposite of what was happening. I think somewhere down the line, the German agent discovers that the scientist had Jewish friends? And that this contributes to what the scientist does next.
Staging a grand demonstration that they can now acquire any resource they want for an unlimited duration, the scientist calibrates the machine to pump out high quality crude oil into drums. This immediately causes excitement among the Nazis attending the meeting, and their reports to Hitler influences him to begin the invasion of Russia, confident with its success despite the lack of preparation or supplies.
The scientist then creates a final demonstration of the machine, and this time a high level group of Nazis attends, with some historical Nazis like Goering or Himmler. The scientist suddenly denounces the group with a speech, revealing his utter contempt of them and their ideology, and with the help of an Alien being (or maybe just himself, details are fuzzy at this point) he escapes through his portal with the machine suddenly exploding behind him.
The Nazis that attended the demonstration are shocked and speechless, knowing full well that without their ace in the hole, the invasion of Russia will turn badly for them. In the aftermath, the unnamed German official details their attempt to fix the machine, but it takes so long that by 1945 the war is already over for them and the project is dead.
The story ends with the CIA agent commenting that further investigation is required or something and I think the CIA Director adds some commentary to the memo implying that a new machine is underway in Area 51.

"Secret Unattainable" by van Vogt? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238293/trying-to-find-a-sci-fi-short-story-world-war-2-german-scientists-trying-to-fi/238295#238295

WOW! Thanks Clara! YES this is exactly it! Thank you! (And holy cow...the way I'm remembering the story is super bad lmao)

Your memory was fine - you gave plenty of detail to identify the story.
